# Do I need an extra license to control access to Sharepoint Online from unmanaged devices?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a Office 365 for business Sharepoint Online environment and struggle to control access from unmanaged devices. Users use family laptops without logging to the local OS. When a authorised user opens a document in Sharepoint with a local App (Word) the service and credentials are cached and the next user of the laptop has onautorized access to Sharepoint. I think this is the same issue with internet cafe devices. How can I control access of Sharepoint Online from unmaged devices?
Do I need an additional license to configure this?
Pleas help
Jan

Answer (score 0):

To configure control access from unmanaged devices in SharePoint Online, we just need the account who is SharePoint or global admin in Office 365. And configure it in the SharePoint Admin center. There is no need for an extra license.

Reference: [Control access from unmanaged devices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-from-unmanaged-devices)

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same solution as JSFace is. In my E1 license for O365 the Admin portal redirects me to buy additional EnterpriseMobility+Security licenses if when I want to configure Control for unmanaged devices. @Hellofiona_MSFT Can you point me towards an instruction which describes configuring this without an EM+S license?